# cp: failed to preserve ownership error when mounted manually

Tags: linux, file-permissions, mount

I copied files from a partition of bootable pendrive using

```
sudo cp -Rrf --preserve=all /media/Necktwi/BOOT/* BOOT/
```

I could able copy back as it is using `sudo cp -Rrf --preserve=all BOOT* /media/Necktwi/BOOT/`
when ubuntu mounts the partition.

But when I mount using

```
sudo mount -w /dev/sdc1 /mnt/boot
```

and try to copy back all its contents I get `cp: failed to preserve ownership` for each file being copied.

the `/etc/mtab` entry for the partition when ubuntu mounts it is

```
/dev/sdc1 /media/Necktwi/boot vfat rw,nosuid,nodev,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush,uhelper=udisks2 0 0
```

the `/etc/mtab` entry for the partion when I mount with `mount` command above is

```
/dev/sdc1 /mnt/boot vfat rw 0 0
```

so I think I should specify some extra options in my `mount` command. My partition is `fat16`. 
How to avoid the `cp: failed to preserve ownership` error?

Comment: Why was this question closed? It is a good question and the first google result when searching "cp failed to preserve ownership".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The FAT file system has no support for ownership. So what Linux does is it simulated the owner and group fields of the file by passing `uid=1000,gid=1000` to mount which says: "Every file and directory is owned by 1000 and group 1000."

To find out what these IDs mean, use `getent`:

```
getent passwd 1000
```

gives you the owner (user) and

```
getent group 1000
```

gives you the group.

To fix the error, use

sudo mount -o uid=1000,gid=1000 /dev/sdc1 /mnt/boot

but the other options work around other, important issues with FAT and Linux so a better solution is to take all of them and mount via a script.

```
#!/bin/bash
options="rw,nosuid,nodev,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush,uhelper=udisks2"
mount -o "$options" /dev/sdc1 /mnt/boot
```

and invoke the script with `sudo`.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure what `uhelper` is for. Maybe you should/can/have to exclude that one.